# Navigator: push everything after the home route

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I have a `home` route that manages the content to be shown to the user based on several factors e.g. if the user is signed in or not. For this reason, I am also injecting providers in the `home` or `/` route as opposed to traditionally defining them inside the `runApp()` method. This is because not all providers would work if the user is not signed in. So I have to inject them at the right place to make sure everything works fine.

```
return MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    '/': (_) => LandingPage(), // providers are defined inside LandingPage()
  },
);
```

So whenever I push a new route using:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SomeRoute(),
        ),
      );
```

The new route nests after `MaterialApp` instead of `LandingPage` (I see this in the Widget Tree of the DevTools). Consequently, the providers are not found since they are defined inside `LandingPage` and not inside the `runApp()` method.

This is somewhat counter intuitive since my `home` or `/` is defined to be `LandingPage`. So every new route should be added after it.

How can I insert a new route after `LandingPage`, and also if possible, make it as the default behaviour?

UPDATE:

Code for `LandingPage`:

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _firebaseInitialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  final String _usersCollection = 'users';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _firebaseInitialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              Provider(
                create: (_) => FirebaseAuth.instance,
              ),
              Provider(
                create: (_) => FirebaseFirestore.instance,
              ),
              Provider(
                create: (_) => FirebaseFunctions.instance,
              ),
              Provider(
                create: (_) => FirebaseStorage.instance,
              ),
            ],
            child: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return StreamBuilder<User>(
                  stream: Provider.of<FirebaseAuth>(context).userChanges(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                      var user = snapshot.data;
                      if (user == null) {
                        return LoginPage();
                      }
                      return MultiProvider(
                        providers: [
                          ChangeNotifierProvider(
                            create: (_) => AfterLoginProvider(),
                            lazy: false,
                          ),
                        ],
                        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                          stream: Provider.of<FirebaseFirestore>(context)
                              .collection(_usersCollection)
                              .doc(user.uid)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.active) {

                              if (!snapshot.data.exists) {
                                return CreateProfile();
                              }

                              return HomePage();
                            }
                            return ProgressIndicatorPage();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return ProgressIndicatorPage();
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
        return ProgressIndicatorPage();
      },
    );
  }
```

WidgetTree from Debugger:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your `LandingPage` widget code? And code of screen where you are moving from routes.

Comment: @fartem I have added the code for `LandingPage`. The code for second screen is nothing but a `StatefulWidget`. I use `Navigator` to push it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right solution or not, but I have come with a workaround. Instead of `return HomePage()`, do this:

```
return Navigator(
  key: homePageRoute,
  onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => HomePage(),
  ),
);
```

also define `homePageRoute` using:

```
static final homePageRoute = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Finally, to push a new route, push using:

```
LandingPage.homePageRoute.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (_) => NewRoute(),
));
```

This pushes a new route where exactly the `Navigator` is defined with the key `homePageRoute`. Hence, `AfterLoginProvider()` is still available in the Widget tree above the route.